# Duplicate Zip entry while creating release build

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

Here is the error i get when i try to build a release apk after integrating Optimizely. and i have proguard enabled.

```
 Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write  
    [.../app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/jars/3/1f/main.ja] 
    (Can't read [.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files 
2.1/com.noveogroup.android/android-
logger/1.3.6/5cb3345e23efd3d3a195eb8c4ae5b627189f8159/android-logger-
1.3.6.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [org/b/c/a.class == 
android-logger-1.3.6.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]))
```

Comment: You have added any .jar file in libs folder.

Comment: @MD no i haven't

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in build.gradle and Rebuild again project;

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer..Try this. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have this too :) It only started happening after integrating Optimizely. Optimizely internally uses the nova logger and that has a dependency clash with some other library that we have

Comment: @SayedJalilHassan: did you figure out how to get past this issue? Running into this with nova logger too. Thanks!

Comment: We ended up not using optimizely. Ask the library owners for help.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have added different versioned files of same classes jar file.

Comment: i haven't added any jars.

Comment: usually this exception occurs only if you have same class name in different package/file.